# move draggable behind element

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable element and a non draggable element with a higher z-index. If I drag the draggable over the non draggable it disappear behind it and that's fine.

But now I want to be able to still drag the element even if its behind the other element. But that's not working, when the draggable is behind the non draggable it gets stuck there.

```js
$('#draggable').draggable({stack: 'span'});
```

```css
#draggable {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 50;
 }
 
 #element
 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<span id="draggable">Drag Me</span>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the CSS attribute `pointer-events: none;` to the non-draggable object cause all event handlers to not trigger the object itself but the objects behind.

```js
$('#draggable').draggable({stack: 'span'});
```

```css
#draggable {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 50;
 }
 
 #element
 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<span id="draggable">Drag Me</span>
<div id="element"></div>
```